# Issue in accessing Sharepoint service from Flex

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to access getListItems method of the Lists service of Sharepoint from Flex using WebService.

It is working fine when I omit the query and the viewFields nodes in the request xml.
But if I add any query or FieldRef in Viewfields it is throwing error from the service.

Below is the code.

```
<mx:WebService id="ws2" wsdl="{url}/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx?WSDL"  result="ws2result(event)" fault="ws2fault(event)"  showBusyCursor="true">    
        <mx:operation name="GetListItems" resultFormat="e4x">
            <mx:request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                <listName>{listId}</listName>
                <viewName>{viewId}</viewName>
                <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Locations'/></ViewFields>
            </mx:request>
        </mx:operation>
    </mx:WebService>
```

It is working fine without the ViewFields.

Can we use the ViewFields and query from flex?

Also is there any way to get the sum of items satisfying a specific condetions using this service?

---

Applied the new format. But still its throwing error.

The SOAP message captured from fiddler.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>  
    <tns:GetListItems xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">  <tns:listName>{0A1C8CDA-E738-46B7-923D-1D2C599D960F}</tns:listName>  
    <tns:viewFields>  
    <tns:Name>ID</tns:Name>  
    </tns:viewFields>  
    </tns:GetListItems>  
    </SOAP-ENV:Body> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But the message in the operation tag is passed as below.

```
<mx:operation name="GetListItems" >
            <mx:request xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                <listName>\{0A3C3DCA-E744-46C7-916D-1D2C539A960F\}</listName>
        <viewFields>
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            </ViewFields>
        </viewFields>
    </mx:request>
</mx:operation>
```

Comment: Try adding a `format` attribute to the request element: `<mx:request format="xml" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">`

Comment: Thanks a lot CBono. I added the format="xml" and its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell for sure without seeing a sample of the actual SOAP message going over the wire, but I believe you're missing some containing elements in the request.

For your query, it needs to be structured as:

```
<query>
  <Query>
    <{CAML QUERY HERE}>
  </Query>
</query>
```

Note the case of the containing `<query>`. Same song, different verse for ViewFields:

```
<viewFields>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="foo" />
  </ViewFields>
</viewFields>
```

QueryOptions must also be contained in a `<queryOptions>` element. Crazy SharePoint!

Comment: Thank you CBono.

I tried the new format. Still it is giving error.  I checked the SOAP message with fiddler. It shows some difference from the actual format. I havee edited the question to add the current SOAP message.

I think flex does some auto formatting on the message. Is this the issue?  Is there any way to avoid the auto formatting?